# org-agenda-files is a dir, but can't cycle

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I want to cycle through the org-agenda-files who's value is:

```
org-agenda-files is a variable defined in ‘org.el’.
Its value is ("/home/jenia/Documents/org/")
Original value was nil
```

But when I press `C-'` I'm only taken to the very first (alphabetically) file in that dir.

How do I cycle through all the files in the dir?

Here is the dir contents:

```
  -rw-r--r--  1 jenia jenia    965 10-02 20:03 arch.org
  -rw-r--r--  1 jenia jenia   2000 10-15 18:00 bash.org
  -rw-r--r--  1 jenia jenia    412 2016-04-03  calc.org
   ....
```

Thanks

Comment: This seems to work as expected on my end (using developmental version
of Org).  Each call to `org-cycle-agenda-files` visits the next file
in the directory.